# How to make a facet wrap readable

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have created a great facet_wrap plot with ggplot but I can't read it!

[image]

You may be able to see tiny writing on the x axis (it is there) but needs to be much clearer.

So I wondered about maybe spreading the facet_wrap over multiple pages but I don't think this can be done with facet_wrap according to answers on google/here.

The other solution may be to wrap the long x-axis labels so they don't space the facet wrap plots so much but this looks like its also not possible.

Does anyone have any ideas. I'm happy to drop facet_wrap if needed.

Here is the code I'm using at the moment

```
ggplot(df.l, aes(sample, hgnc_symbol)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + facet_wrap(~chr,scales="free",nrow = 4)+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

I can't dput as way too much data but here's the structure.

```
'data.frame':   8550 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ chr            : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ binnum         : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ leftPos        : num  4864877 14283067 21786817 33465769 45300540 ...
 $ hgnc_symbol    : chr  "MIR4417,MIR4689,NPHP4" "FHAD1,TMEM51-AS1,KAZN,TBCAP2,TMEM51,C1orf195" "MIR4418,RNU6-1022P,RNU6-776P,MIR4684,RN7SL386P,RN7SL186P,CELA3B,CDC42-IT1,CDC42,CELA3A,EPHB2,ZBTB40,ZBTB40-IT1,LDLRAD2,HSPG2,EP"| __truncated__ "RNA5SP42,TLR12P,C1orf94,HMGB4,HSPD1P14,ZSCAN20,CSMD2,CSMD2-AS1" ...
 $ Stop           : num  5864876 15283067 22786817 34465769 46300539 ...
 $ MergeCol       : chr  "1:4864876:5864876" "1:14283067:15283067" "1:21786817:22786817" "1:33465769:34465769" ...
 $ chromosome_name: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sample         : chr  "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" ...
 $ value          : num  101.6 53.7 144.7 84 101.6 ...
 $ id             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "reshapeLong")=List of 4
  ..$ varying:List of 1
  .. ..$ value: chr  "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" "ZSTumour12_OCCAMS_ED_008_SLX.9396.FastSeqJ.fq.gz" "ZSTumour13_OCCAMS_AH_086_SLX.9396.FastSeqK.fq.gz" "ZSTumour2_OCCAMS_AH_058_SLX.9396.FastSeqB.fq.gz" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "v.names")= chr "value"
  .. ..- attr(*, "times")= chr  "ZSTumour10_OCCAMS_AH_088_SLX.9396.FastSeqH.fq.gz" "ZSTumour12_OCCAMS_ED_008_SLX.9396.FastSeqJ.fq.gz" "ZSTumour13_OCCAMS_AH_086_SLX.9396.FastSeqK.fq.gz" "ZSTumour2_OCCAMS_AH_058_SLX.9396.FastSeqB.fq.gz" ...
  ..$ v.names: chr "value"
  ..$ idvar  : chr "id"
  ..$ timevar: chr "sample"
```

Comment: I'd probably break the data up into separate facet_wraps that are generated independently.  You can adjust numbering accordingly. Another option would be to increase the font size of the axis labels and export the image much larger as a PDF (vector) and scale it accordingly.

Alternatively use a few facet_grids (with the broken up data) which might look neater.

Comment: +1 for exporting image to a large size. Check ggsize() arguments, maximum size and width are pretty arbritary, so you can easily go to poster size (24"x36") if that's what it takes.

Comment: Hi. What is ggsize(). I can't seem to find it on google

Comment: They probably meant `ggsave`.